# Code is not compiling with cmake on MacOS? (SFML)

Tags: c++, macos, cmake, sfml

I am new to CMake and my code isn't linking correctly when I run make after cmake.

The code wouldn't compile at all if I used apple clang's default compiler, so I changed the compiler in the CMakeLists.txt file to use g++ instead of AppleClang using these lines:

```
###########################
# CMake Build Environment #
###########################
#
# You can set the following Environment variables:
#
# CMAKE_MODULE_PATH to the search path for cmake modules (e.g., SFML.cmake)
# CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE to override the default build type. Valid options are 'release', 'profile' and 'debug'
#
#########################################


set(CMAKE_C_COMPILER "gcc-10")
set(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER "g++-10")
#set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11")
#set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)
```

It's supposed to use C++11, but I'm not sure if it does that. When I uncomment out the CMAKE Flags it still gives the same error.

When I run make:

```
[ 91%] Built target Bird_core
Scanning dependencies of target bird
[ 95%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/bird.dir/bin/bird.cpp.o
[100%] Linking CXX executable bird
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "__ZN2sf4Font12loadFromFileERKNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEE", referenced from:
      __ZN13ResourceCache16loadFontResourceERKNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEES7_ in libBird_core.a(ResourceCache.cpp.o)
  "__ZN2sf6StringC1EPKcRKSt6locale", referenced from:
      __ZN9__gnu_cxx13new_allocatorIN2sf12RenderWindowEE9constructIS2_JNS1_9VideoModeERA11_KcNS1_5Style9._anon_74ERNS1_15ContextSettingsEEEEvPT_DpOT0_ in libBird_core.a(Game.cpp.o)
  "__ZN2sf6StringC1ERKNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEERKSt6locale", referenced from:
      __ZN19PlayingMenuActivity6updateERKf in libBird_core.a(PlayingMenuActivity.cpp.o)
      __ZN6Button9setStringERKNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEE in libBird_core.a(Button.cpp.o)
  "__ZN2sf7Texture12loadFromFileERKNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEERKNS_4RectIiEE", referenced from:
      __ZN13ResourceCache19loadTextureResourceERKNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEES7_ in libBird_core.a(ResourceCache.cpp.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [bird] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/bird.dir/all] Error 2
```

It should not be an issue with the code (it works on Linux/Windows and I changed the compiler from Apple clang to g++). The parts of the code that are triggering this are just font.loadFromFile() and texture.loadFromFile() which are from a library, SFML. I think its with how I've linked SFML or something else.

Any help is appreciated, thank you!

Comment: Can you show the code that produces the error?

Comment: `Debug % cmake ..` `Debug % make`

Comment: That is not C++ code. Show the C++ code that generates this particular problem, at least the line you think it is.

Comment: Oh, I think the C++ code is fine (it works and compiles and runs on my linux computer). It just won't compile on mac for some reason

Comment: Show. The. C++. Code. Please. Maybe GCC is happy with it, and clang isn't.

Comment: oh sorry, my bad! I didn't know that could even be possible (I'm a noob) `if (_buttons.find(button) == _buttons.end())
        _buttons[button] = adjacencies;
}
`

Comment: Apple clang defaults to C++98. The cmake file likely doesn't specify the version of C++ to use. I would want to see that before the code. But both should be posted for completeness.

Comment: Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/67067811/edit) your question to contain a [mre] with full source code, either the compiler command line or the cmake file and the full error message

Comment: Is your sfml library also compiled with gcc? Clang uses a different standard library so c++ libraries compiled with clang won't work with gcc (unless you tell clang to use gcc's standard library)

Answer (score 0):

[Cross-post](https://en.sfml-dev.org/forums/index.php?topic=27993.0) from the SFML forum

The std::string ABI was changed in GCC for C++11.

So you need to make sure SFML is compiled with the same runtime than your application is.
And/or can try to enable/disable the C++11 standard for your code.

Personally, I'd recommend sticking with Xcode/clang